# Add string to specific position

Tags: c, encoding

I'm fairly new to C, I have an encoding rule that is basicaly, if there is Z in the string, we add another Z, if there are no Z, just repeat

Example

input: STZCK -> output: STZZCK

I managed to add another Z but just at the end of string, I have to add after the found one.

I tried

```
char * encoding (char * str){
    
    int size = strlen(str);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    
        if(str[i] == 'Z'){

            char ch = 'Z';
            strncat(str, &ch, 1);

        }
        else if(str[i] != 'Z'){
            str[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    
    return str;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The arguments to `strcat` and `strncat` need to be `\0`-terminated strings. You must not pass a pointer to a character.

Comment: You need to move all the characters to make room for extra in the middle.

Comment: It is usually not possible to encode a string in place, because usually it will end up being longer. It's probably better to return a new string that is dynamically allocated.

Comment: If you're doing the mapping in place, you must provide a long enough buffer in the argument `str`, and you must copy the tail of the string (after the `Z` you just found) up one place, and then add a `Z` after the current position, and step past the added `Z` before the next iteration.  Another design would have the user of the function supply a destination string into which the original is copied, with Z replaced by two Z's.  I'm dubious about the `strncat()` call — that's a function with horrible semantics for the interface.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `strlen()` call; you can iterate over `for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) { … }`.

Comment: So, if input is 4 `ZZZZ` output will be 8 `ZZZZZZZZ`?

Comment: What do you mean by *if there are no Z, just repeat*? Should `ABC` turn into `ABCABC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
 char* encoding(char* str) {
    int len = strlen(str);

    // count Z to see how much bigger the result will be 
    int countZ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'Z') countZ++;
    }
    // make return string large enough
    char* retStr = malloc(len + countZ + 1);

    // copy old to new with added Zs  
    int retOff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        retStr[retOff++] = str[i];
        if (str[i] == 'Z') retStr[retOff++] = 'Z';
    }
    retStr[retOff] = 0;
    return retStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify if your function receives a buffer with enough space for the output string or if your function needs to dynamically allocate memory.

In the first case you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void encode(char *d, const char *s)
{
    do {
        *d++ = *s;
        if (*s == 'Z') {
            *d++ = *s;
        }
    } while (*s++ != 0);
}

int main(void) {
    char *src[] = {"STZCK", "HELLO", "ZZ", "", NULL};
    char dst[256];
    
    for (char **s = src; *s != NULL; ++s) {
        encode(dst, *s);
        printf("%s -> %s\n", *s, dst);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```